# Python 2.7 Pause till backspace key is pressed

Tags: python-2.7, backspace

I need to pause a python 2.7 script from running and I have used the os.system("pause"), which continues on any key being pressed.
How can I get it to pause and only continue when the backspace key is pressed? It needs to ignore all other keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a program running from your shell cannot normally take static key input (like without hitting enter) without using an external library (I use `PyGame` or `TKinter`, but `curses` should also work.)

For `PyGame`:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init();
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode();

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_BACKSPACE]:
        pass
        // Do your thing
    pygame.display.flip()
```